# CSV Writing to File Difficulties

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, python-2.x, file-writing

I am supposed to add a specific label to my `CSV` file based off conditions. The `CSV` file has 10 columns and the third, fourth, and fifth columns are the ones that affect the conditions the most and I add my label on the tenth column. I have code here which ended in an infinite loop:

```
import csv
import sys

w = open(sys.argv[1], 'w')
r = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')

reader = csv.reader(r)
writer = csv.writer(w)

for row in reader:
    if row[2] or row[3] or row[4] == '0':
        row[9] == 'Label'
        writer.writerow(row)

w.close()
r.close()
```

I do not know why it would end in an infinite loop.

EDIT:  I made a mistake and my original infinite loop program had this line:

```
w = open(sys.argv[1], 'a')
```

I changed `'a'` to `'w'` but this ended up erasing the entire `CSV` file itself. So now I have a different problem.

Comment: `if row[2] == '0' or row[3] == '0' or row[4] == '0':`

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @EricJ. Sorry about that. I added it to the tags

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a problem here `if row[2] or row[3] or row[4] == '0':` and here `row[9] == 'Label'`, you can use [**`any`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) to check several variables equal to the same value, and use `=` to assign a value, also i would recommend to use [**`with open`**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

Additionally you can't read and write at the same time in `csv` file, so you need to save your changes to a new csv file, you can remove the original one after and rename the new one using [**`os.remove`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove) and [**`os.rename`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename):

```
import csv
import sys    
import os

with open('some_new_file.csv', 'w') as w, open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as r:
    reader, writer = csv.reader(r), csv.writer(w)
    for row in reader:
        if any(x == '0' for x in (row[2], row[3], row[4])):
            row[9] = 'Label'
        writer.writerow(row)

os.remove('{}'.format(sys.argv[1]))
os.rename('some_new_file.csv', '{}'.format(sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: Thank you this has prevented infinite loop in the program in append mode. However it didn't seem to have worked correctly as the label wasn't added.

Comment: there is another problem, you can't open the same file for writing and reading

Comment: I tried to change `sys.argv[1]` to be written to `test.csv` with the file I have to be read. However `test.csv` ended up the same as the original.

Comment: you need to use w mode and new file, i updated the answer

Comment: you can delete the original file after and rename new one if you want

Comment: I have tried the new version and my new file, the one to have the labels, has become completely empty. Why would this happen?

Comment: This seems to have worked! Thank you for your help. I do not know why it separates the labelled with the part that isn't but I'll have to work on that. EDIT: It turned out I needed to create the file through the program first.

Comment: i figure it out, you had row[9] == 'Label'  instead row[9] = 'Label'

Comment: also i assume you want all lines in your new file even unchanged ones, i made changes and i added remove/rename files part

Answer (score 4):

You can write to a [tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) and just use `in` to test for the `"0"` as you are matching a full string not a substring so you won't save anything by using any as you create a tuple of three elements so you may as well slice or just test for membership regardless, then you just replace the original file with [shutil.move](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move):

```
import csv
import sys    
from shutil import move
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

with NamedTemporaryFile("w", dir=".", delete=False) as w, open(sys.argv[1]) as r:
    reader, writer = csv.reader(r), csv.writer(w)
    writer.writerows(row[:-1] + ['Label'] if "0" in row[2:5] else row 
                     for row in reader)

move(w.name, sys.argv[1])
```

`sys.argv[1]` is also you file name and a string so that is all you need to pass.

Comment: i'm giving my bounty to you, since you are the only one who posted a good answer besides me

Answer (score 0):

I think the Problem is in lines

```
w = open(sys.argv[1], 'w')
r = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
```

You are opening the same file for reading and writing.So try using different file name.